# My mead wont stay carbonated!

Tags: carbonation, wine, mead, brewing

I have a strawberry mead that I am attempting to make sparkling. I added sugar drops to each bottle (Im bottling in 12 oz bottles) and after about a week it seems very carbonated but when I pop the cap off I have to do it slowly. I open it a bit, the mead bubbles up like a shaken up soda pop, and then I have to close the lid and let the bubbles subside before openning some more and starting the process over.

Can anyone tell me how to keep it from bubbling up when I open it??

Comment: what was your F.G.? what size bottles? and what is the serving temp when you had it gush?

Comment: From the title of your post, do you also mean that after the big pressure release and bubbling up that it otherwise doesn't seem carbonated?

Comment: @jsolarski The F.G. was about 1.1 I believe. Ive tried room temperature and refrigerated (about 70 F and 40 F). The bottles are typical 12 oz beer bottles.

Comment: @Dave After the cap is removed and pressure is released, the mead is only very slightly carbonated.

Comment: To me it sounds like the bottles may some residue left behind creating nucleation point for the CO2.

Comment: @jsolarski Will strawberry particles cause this? There is some strawberry in some of the bottles.

Comment: Yes it could cause this, in theory.

Comment: Please also indicate what size are the sugar drops (brand), bottle size and type of caps used.

Comment: @Philippe I'll have to check when I get hone. At work now.

Comment: @Philippe Mangrove Jacks Carbonation Drops, 12oz beer bottles, and Brewcraft caps

Comment: Did you refrigerate for more than a day? I don't know how long it takes, but dissolution is not immediate.

Answer (score 4):

If you are otherwise happy with the carbonation level of the mead, once it is capped and in the bottle your options are limited.  Chilling it before opening, and avoiding agitating it are about your only options.

Comment: Im not happy with the level of carbonation. I suppose it would do but I would like to know how to make it better. Or at least understand the factor causing the carbonation loss to try to avoid that in future batches.

Comment: Chilling is the thing to try first.  Keep the bottle in the fridge for a few hour, or even in the freezer for some time.  The colder the better (not freezing though).  Then see if it makes any difference when you open it...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are having nucleation issues and losing your carbonation when you open it up.  Chilling the bottles and pouring it off quickly will hopefully let you retain some carbonation.  Not much more you can do than that now that its bottled.

I'd just learn from it and prepare for next time.

Many meads will have dusty sediment in them post ferment.  If carbonating that can lead to issues with nucleation.  I'd recommend next time to rack too secondary for fruiting.  Then rack again to a clean fermentor to clear it still of the fruit debris.  Be very mindful when racking to a bottling bucket to keep any debris out.  This should vastly reduce the opportunity for nucleation.